# Is there a way to add metadata in py files for grouping tests?

Tags: python, metadata, unittest2

Lets say I have the following testcases in different files

- TestOne.py {tags: One, Two}
- TestTwo.py {tags: Two}
- TestThree.py {tags: Three}

Each of which inherits from unittest.TestCase. Is there any ability in python to embed metadata information within these files, so that I can have a main.py script to search for those tags and execute only those testcases?

For Eg: If I want to execute testcases with {tags: Two} then only testcases TestOne.py and TestTwo.py should be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`py.test`](http://pytest.org/latest/contents.html) testing framework has support for meta data, via what they call [markers](http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html).

For `py.test` test cases are functions that have names starting with "test", and which are in modules with names starting with "test". The tests themselves are simple `assert` statements. `py.test` can also run tests for the `unittest` library, and IIRC Nose tests.

The meta data consists of dynamically generated decorators for the test functions. The decorators have the form: `@pytest.mark.my_meta_name`. You can choose anything for `my_meta_name`. There are a few predefined markers that you can see with `py.test --markers`.

Here is an adapted snippet from their documentation:

```
# content of test_server.py

import pytest

@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_send_http():
    pass # perform some webtest test for your app

def test_always_succeeds():
    assert 2 == 3 - 1

def test_will_always_fail():
    assert 4 == 5
```

You select marked tests with the `-m` command line option of the test runner. To selectively run `test_send_http()` you enter this into a shell:

```
py.test -v -m webtest
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's more easy to define tags in the main module, but if it's important for you to save them with test files, it could be a good solution to define it in test files like this:

In TestOne.py:

```
test_tags = ['One', 'Two']
...
```

Then you can read all tags in the `initialize` function of your main module in this way:

```
test_modules = ['TestOne', 'TestTwo', 'TestThree']
test_tags_dict = {}

def initialize():
    for module_name in test_modules:
        module = import_string(module)

        if hasattr(module, 'test_tags'):
            for tag in module.test_tags:
                if tag not in test_tags_dict:
                    test_tags_dict[tag] = []
                test_tags_dict[tag].append(module)
```

So you can implement a `run_test_with_tag` function to run all tests for an specific tag:

```
def run_test_with_tag(tag):
    for module in test_tags_dict.get(tag, []):
        # Run module tests here ...
```